# How to install Geany 1.28 on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, geany

The official repository offers the 1.27 version, but I need 1.28, which comes with `save on focus out` plugin (not available in the plugins for 1.27. Is there any option, apart from compiling the sources?

Also tried by adding a PPA: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geany-dev/ppa`, but a normal installation will keep downloading the 1.27 version.

Update: Have found the plugin installed and running on an old PC with Geany 1.25. All I need is the file `saveactions.so`, which in this case is stored in the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/geany` folder. But what is the plugin that installs `saveactions`? Would it simply work to copy the file to the new system and make the plugin active?

Solved: `saveaction` is in `geany-common`, so a `sudo apt-get install geany-common`, enabling in `Edit > Preferences > General > Startup > Enable plugin support`, and finally activation in `Tools > Plugin manager > saving actions` will enable the `Save Actions` menu in `Edit > Plugin Preferences`.

Comment: That PPA doesn't have 1.28 in it.

Comment: As far as copying the .so, likely won't work but you have it so try & see. After copying & a `sudo ldconfig` you could run `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/geany/saveactions.so` & if you get any not founds then it certainly won't work. 1.28 is in 16.10, you could get the source & rebuild it on your 16.04 install.

Comment: You're right @DKBose, `saveaction` is in `geany-common`, so a `sudo apt-get install geany-common`, enabling in `Edit > Preferences > General > Startup > Enable plugin support`, and finally activation in `Tools > Plugin manager > saving actions` will enable the `Save Actions` menu in `Edit > Plugin Preferences`. (But in an even older version -1.23- I still can't find the `save when out of focus option`, but the auto, instant and backup options only.)

Comment: @DKBose Sure, it is just that and I'm using it in higher versions, just wanted to note that the 1.23 version of Geany does not provide it for some reason.